# Angular JS controller detect third-party event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, jasny-bootstrap

I have an Angular 1.4.9 app.  I'm using a third party JS plugin (Jasny Bootstrap).  It has some JS components, which appear to use simple JQuery.

Their docs say that the plugin emits events at key points, such as "itemShown".  I was wondering if I can detect this in my page's controller and act upon it, as in:

"on itemShown function () {..."

Comment: Have you considered adding it inside a directive instead of the controller?

Comment: Your question might get more attention if you provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) showing your problem.

Comment: It's too difficult to re-create the set-up on one of those sites.  I usually do, but this involves several external libraries etc.

Answer (score 0):

### Handling Custom jQuery Events in AngularJS

The following example shows a custom directive that detects a custom jQuery events and invokes a function defined by an attribute.

```
app.directive("onBsShowOffcanvas", function($parse) {
    return function linkFn(scope, elem, attrs) {
        var fn = $parse(attrs.onBsShowOffCanvas);
        elem.on("show.bs.offcanvas", function(e) {
            fn.assign(scope, {$event: e});
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
});
```

To use the directive in your HTML:

```
<div on-bs-show-offcanvas="offcanvasHandler($event)">
```

I recommend that the event object be exposed as `$event` since that is customary with AngularJS event directives.

> ### $event
>
> Directives like `ngClick` and `ngFocus` expose a `$event` object within the scope of that expression. The object is an instance of a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present or a similar jqLite object.

-- [AngularJS Developer Guide -- $event](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-)

Comment: where in that directive would my code go, e.g. `log.debug('hello world')`?  I tried inserting it after `scope.$apply` but no dice.

Answer (score 0):

If you embed jQuery in your app (because Angular embeds jQlite by default, but not jQuery), here is one solution.

You can do it from the controller, after your element is ready:

```
$element.ready(function () {
    $('#offcanvasId').on('hide.bs.offcanvas', function(){
        //...
    })
});
```

Nonetheless, there must be some workarounds without jQuery.

You can see more on the documentation https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: Thanks.  Since I am using Bootstrap 3.35, I am using jQuery as well.  I will try this.